# Why is this surface red? Is it because of the lighting?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting, hdri

The bedsheet is supposed to have the sunlight hitting it from the windows. The room has peach coloured walls. Are they somehow contributing in the redness of the surface?
The Bedsheet surface has a Diffuse BSDF as the material. Roughness 0.2. I am using HDR for lighting.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *disclaimer - It is just a hunch.
Have you applied subsurface scattering?

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have sub-surface scattering turned on for the walls (or maybe another object)in your room. Look through all your materials and check that it's turned to 0 (if that's what you want).